# Pivoting without aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to [pivot without aggregation](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-without-aggregation), and running into a bit of a wall.

Here's the sample T-SQL I'm trying to get to work:

```
declare @optionalFields table (ParentId int, Name nvarchar(50), Value nvarchar(50));
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field1', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field2', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field3', '42');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field1', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field2', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field3', '24');

declare @data table (Id int, Name nvarchar(50));
insert into @data values (1, 'Test record 1');
insert into @data values (2, 'Test record 2');

declare @joined table (Id int, Name nvarchar(50), OptionalFieldName nvarchar(50), OptionalFieldValue nvarchar(50));
insert into @joined
select 
     data.Id
    ,data.Name
    ,opt.Name
    ,opt.Value
from @data data
    inner join @optionalFields opt on data.Id = opt.ParentId

declare @cols as nvarchar(max) = 
    stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(OptionalFieldName) from @joined for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

select * into #tmp from @joined
-- just to see that it's returning the expected values (it does)
select
     Id
    ,Name
    ,OptionalFieldName
    ,OptionalFieldValue
    ,row_number() over (partition by Id order by Id) RN 
from #tmp -- this is the FROM clause in the below dynamic-sql query

declare @query as nvarchar(max) = '
    select Id, Name, ' + @cols + '
    from (select Id, Name, OptionalFieldName, OptionalFieldValue, row_number() over (partition by Id order by Id) RN from #tmp) src 
    pivot (max(OptionalFieldName) for RN in (' + @cols + ')) pvt';

execute(@query);
drop table #tmp;
```

SSMS is giving me 2 errors:

> - Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>     *Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.*
> - Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>     *The incorrect value "Field1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.*

The "debug" select statement is returning this:

[image: 3 rows per "test record", as expected]

The article (link above) seemed very promising, however I can't seem to be able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Or is this article outright wrong and what I'm trying to do is impossble?

I've seen a number of similar SO questions, but either they involved all-numeric fields that could "just work" with aggregation, or they involved known columns that could be implemented as simple joins - I don't know what `OptionalFieldName` values I'm going to be selecting, and the `OptionalFieldValue` values are strings that simply can't be aggregated, at least AFAIK.

Comment: Well, for one, you're pivoting for RN in [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] etc when RN is the ROW_NUMBER(). What I'm guessing you mean to do is pivot the optionalfieldvalue for each optionalfieldname?

Comment: @ZLK indeed, but `OptionalFieldValue` cannot be aggregated as it's a varchar... pivoting on RN is used to trick the pivoting, as shown in the article I linked to.

Comment: uh... What exactly is your desired output? I'm not sure this is what you want but try adding a @cols2 variable that's the same as @cols but the select statement is this: `', MAX(' + quotename(OptionalFieldName) + ') ' + quotename(OptionalFieldName)` then change your @query to: `declare @query as nvarchar(max) = '
    select Id, Name, ' + @cols2 + '
    from #tmp
    pivot (max(OptionalFieldValue) for OptionalFieldName in (' + @cols + ')) pvt
 GROUP BY ID, Name';`

Comment: @Mat'sMug You don't need to trick this at all.  Even though the value you need to aggregate is a string you can still use `min`/`max` on it. Here is a demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7786/0  That can be easily converted to dynamic sql (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7790/0).

Comment: @bluefeet as I reed your comment I understand the failure of my answer and simplicity of your solution :) Why haven't I try this myself? I have deleted my answer in shame :)

Comment: @gofr1 No shame, there are different ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on why you are trying to trick this using `row_number()`. Even though you have string values, you can still aggregate it - you just need to use `max` or `min` to get the result.

I'd always recommend trying to write your query with hard-coded values first, especially when using PIVOT before even attempting to use dynamic SQL.   I'm unsure why you can't just write the query this way:

```
select Id, Name, Field1, Field2, Field3
from 
(
  select
     Id
    ,Name
    ,OptionalFieldName
    ,OptionalFieldValue
  from #tmp
) d
pivot
(
  max(OptionalFieldValue)
  for OptionalFieldName in (Field1, Field2, Field3)
) piv;
```

[See a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7786/0).

Then if you really need dynamic SQL, you would just write it:

```
declare @optionalFields table (ParentId int, Name nvarchar(50), Value nvarchar(50));
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field1', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field2', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field3', '42');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field1', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field2', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field3', '24');

declare @data table (Id int, Name nvarchar(50));
insert into @data values (1, 'Test record 1');
insert into @data values (2, 'Test record 2');

declare @joined table (Id int, Name nvarchar(50), OptionalFieldName nvarchar(50), OptionalFieldValue nvarchar(50));
insert into @joined
select 
     data.Id
    ,data.Name
    ,opt.Name
    ,opt.Value
from @data data
    inner join @optionalFields opt on data.Id = opt.ParentId

declare @cols as nvarchar(max);
set @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(OptionalFieldName) 
                   from @joined
                   for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

select * into #tmp from @joined

DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @query = 'SELECT Id, Name,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
             (
                select Id
                  ,Name
                  ,OptionalFieldName
                  ,OptionalFieldValue
                from #tmp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(OptionalFieldValue)
                for OptionalFieldName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7790/0).  Both versions appear to give the result that you have requested.

Comment: Wow, you rock! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: This answer is here only to show another way to accomplish this pivoting. The answer from @bluefeet is the best solution!

Hope I understand what you need right:

```
declare @optionalFields table (ParentId int, Name nvarchar(50), Value nvarchar(50));
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field1', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field2', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (1, 'Field3', '42');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field1', 'Bar');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field2', 'Foo');
insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field3', '24');

declare @data table (Id int, Name nvarchar(50));
insert into @data values (1, 'Test record 1');
insert into @data values (2, 'Test record 2');


select 
     data.Id
    ,data.Name
    ,opt.Name as Name1
    ,opt.Value into #tmp
from @data data
    inner join @optionalFields opt on data.Id = opt.ParentId

declare @cols as nvarchar(max) = 
    stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(Name1) from #tmp for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @cols1 as nvarchar(max) = 
    stuff((select distinct +',MAX(CASE WHEN (pvt1.'+quotename(Name1) +' = ros.RN AND pvt1.id = ros.id) THEN ros.Value ELSE NULL END) as '+quotename(Name1)  from #tmp for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

declare @query as nvarchar(max) = '
 ;WITH cte AS(
 SELECT * FROM #tmp
),

        ros AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Id order by Id) AS [RN],id,Value
        FROM cte),
        pvt1 AS (
    select *
    from (select Id, Name, Name1, row_number() over (partition by Id order by Id) RN 
            from cte) src 
    pivot (max(RN) for Name1 in ('+@cols+')) pvt)

    SELECT pvt1.ID,
            pvt1.Name,
            '+@cols1+'
    FROM pvt1 
    CROSS JOIN ros
    GROUP BY pvt1.ID,
            pvt1.Name'

execute(@query);
drop table #tmp
```

Result:

```
ID  Name            Field1  Field2  Field3
1   Test record 1   Foo     Bar     42
2   Test record 2   Bar     Foo     24
```

And if you add more Fields like `insert into @optionalFields values (2, 'Field4', '15');`, you will get:

```
ID  Name            Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
1   Test record 1   Foo     Bar     42      NULL
2   Test record 2   Bar     Foo     24      15
```